# How to declare variable of Mediaplayer in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have used this format

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

It showing a error "cannot declare a variable of static type 'microsoft.xna.framework.media player'".

How to solve this ?

Comment: having a look [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument10213), you could try something like `MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.new()`

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer is static class. You can't create instance of static class. You can use method of MediaPlayer, in this way:

```
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```